# How to get restored Fragment instance from onCreate's Bundle?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains a few Fragments that are created in onCreate() and returned by a FragmentPagerAdapter (in getItem(int)). This works great. If the Activity is destroyed and then recreated (easy to reproduce by letting the phone go to sleep) the old Fragments are automatically restored by the call to super.onCreate(Bundle) because I'm passing it the 'savedInstanceState'. This is what I want.

The problem is, how do I get a reference to these Fragments? They are being created, yet I cannot access them. Right now I'm re-creating the Fragments every time onCreate() is called, which is not ideal.

There has to be a way to do this, right?

EDIT: I am not using a FragmentManager at all. I am using a FragmentPagerAdapter. An example is below. The custom fragments are created in onCreate() and are what I'd like to have point to the recreated fragments. I need references to this fragments because the activity sometimes calls methods on them.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragment = myCustomFragment1;
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = myCustomFragment2;
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = myCustomFragment3;
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            default:
            case 0:
                return "Fragment Title 1";

            case 1:
                return "Fragment Title 2";

            case 2:
                return "Fragment Title 3";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the fragments by ID or by tag, depending on the way you have created them.

For example, in your `Activity`:

***By ID:***

```
// Fragment setup, with no tag
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_slot_in_the_layout, myFragment);
ft.commit();

...

// Now, we retrieve the fragment, somewhere else. 
// We can only do it by ID as no tag is available.
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_slot_in_the_layout);
```

***By tag:***

```
// Fragment setup, using a tag
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_slot_in_the_layout, myFragment, TAG_THAT_YOU_HAVE_DEFINED);
ft.commit();

...

// Now, we retrieve the fragment, somewhere else. 
// You have the choice, you can retrieve it by ID or by tag as both are available. 
// In this example we retrieve it by tag.
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_THAT_YOU_HAVE_DEFINED);
```

(If you are not using the Support Library, use `Activity.getFragmentManager()` instead of  `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using a FragmentTransaction anywhere. I am simply returning an already-created Fragment in SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(int). I have edited my original question to show this (there isn't room here).